# What is the common protocol between HTTP, SMTP and SIP

Tags: http, tcp, smtp, udp, sip

May not be a relevant question but I was always wondering this.

These 3 protocols are very similar, they contains headers + a payload, have request, response and that's it.

Does this "protocol architecture" is documented somewhere ?

Thanks

Comment: SMTP is very different from the others . You seem to look only at the header+body of the mail - but this is actually not part of SMTP but of the data transferred inside the SMTP DATA command. But in general you'll find a lot of similarities between protocols which were designed around the same time (i.e. SMTP, FTP, NNTP, ...) or which borrowed ideas from each other (RFC821 style header+body in  mails, HTTP and SIP). There is no general "protocol architecture" though, it is more an evolution of protocols where newer ones borrow successful ideas from older.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich mostly agree, but don't you mean RFC822? RFC821 defines SMTP.  I'd have said SMTP is closer to SIP than HTTP (<2) as they involve several round trips between client and server.  also HTTP2 and QUIC/HTTP3 are very different from HTTP1, might be useful for OP to distinguish what they mean

Comment: @SamMason: yes, RFC 822 (or 2822) defines the message format. SIP is a request response protocol like HTTP and with a similar message syntax. But each of these messages in SIP can be sent over a different connection (or connection-like thing for UDP), unlike in HTTP or SMTP. And there are not several round trips in SIP (except a bit for INVITE-200-ACK etc), the different messages in a call are more like multiple request-response pairs with the same cookie (i.e. call-id) in HTTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich interesting!  I was basing my comments on debugging SIP TCP issues (overzealous corporate firewalls) and following the protocol by hand to see where things broke.  I've not implemented/worked-on a real client/server so my comments are a bit naive!